# Adding same text to multiple divs of different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I can add text to a single div (currently, #adXL) using text and file inputs. How can I add that same text and files (from those same text and file inputs) to multiple divs (#adL, #adM, #adS)?

I would also like to be able to add many more divs that receive the same text and file inputs, as well.

Here is my current code:

```js
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
   var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('adXL').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}

document.getElementById('getval2').addEventListener('change', readURL2, true);
function readURL2(){
   var file2 = document.getElementById("getval2").files[0];
   var reader2 = new FileReader();
   reader2.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('logo').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader2.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file2){
      reader2.readAsDataURL(file2);
    }else{
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    var div1 = $('#header')[0];

    $('#text1').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div1.innerHTML = this.value;
    }); 

    var div2 = $('#subHeader')[0];

    $('#text2').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div2.innerHTML = this.value;
    });

    var div3 = $('#button')[0];

    $('#text3').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div3.innerHTML = this.value;
        if(this.value.length > 0) {
            $('#button').css('display', 'block')
        } else {
           $('#button').css('display', 'none')
        }
    });
});
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 14px;
}

#adXL{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 0;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
}

#logo{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size: auto 100%;
   background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-width: 0;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;

}
#adCopy {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#adButtonAndLogo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#header {
  font-size: 52px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 110%;
}

#subHeader {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
background-color: #1D41FF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#adL {
?
}

#adM {
?
}

#adS {
?
}

...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Background Image</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" /> 

<h2>Header</h2><input id="text1" class="textInput">

<h2>Subheader</h2><input id="text2" class="textInput">

<h2>Button Text</h2>
  <input id="text3" class="textInput">
  
  <h2>Logo Image Asset</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval2' name="background-image" />


<div id='adXL' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div id="header" class="changeMe"></div>
    <div id="subHeader" class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>

  </div>
</div>


<div id='adL' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div id="header" class="changeMe"></div>
    <div id="subHeader" class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id='adM' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div id="header" class="changeMe"></div>
    <div id="subHeader" class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id='adS' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div id="header" class="changeMe"></div>
    <div id="subHeader" class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this showing "Apparently this user likes to keep a certain air of mystery about them"?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There should never be more than one element with a particular ID in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the elements you want to add the styles to, the elements you want to add the text to, the elements you want to listen for text changes, and the elements you want to listen for file changes. Then, just iterate over them:

```js
const textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="file"])');
const elementsToChangeOnTextInput = [...document.querySelectorAll('.changeMe')];
const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
const elementsToChangeOnFileInput = ['#adXL', '#adL', '#adM', '#adS']
  .map(selector => document.querySelector);

textInputs.forEach((textInput) => {
  textInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    const newValue = textInput.value;
    elementsToChangeOnTextInput
      .forEach(element => element.textContent = newValue);
  });
});

fileInputs.forEach((fileInput) => {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  if (!file) return;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', function(){
    const imgCSSStr = `url(${reader.result})`;
    elementsToChangeOnFileInput.forEach(element => {
      element.style.backgroundImage = imgCSSStr;
    });
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 14px;
}

#adXL{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 0;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
}

#logo{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size: auto 100%;
   background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-width: 0;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;

}
#adCopy {
  display: flex;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Background Image</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" /> 

<h2>Header</h2><input id="text1" class="textInput">

<h2>Subheader</h2><input id="text2" class="textInput">

<h2>Button Text</h2>
  <input id="text3" class="textInput">
  
  <h2>Logo Image Asset</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval2' name="background-image" />


<div id='adXL' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div class="changeMe"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>

  </div>
</div>


<div id='adL' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div class="changeMe"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id='adM' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div class="changeMe"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id='adS' class="bg-img">
  <div id="adCopy">
 <div class="changeMe"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="adButtonAndLogo">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="changeMe"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works for one file input, but it does not work for the three text inputs (#header, #subHeader, #button), and it does not work for the second file input (#logo).

Comment: Any ideas on how the text inputs and second file input can be included too?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're looking for - if you want to add more selectors to the array there so they're all changed on `loadend`, just type them into the array to expand it. If you want the same thing to happen with the other file input, declare the function standalone and assign it as a listener for both `#getval` and `#getval2`. For the text inputs, you can use a similar method, if that's what you're trying for: declare a single function with an array of selectors inside, and assign it as a listener for all text input elements in question.

Comment: Ok, I'm not how to write all that into the existing JS. What I'm trying to do is replicate how the inputs are live updating into the first div (#adXL), to all the other divs (#adL, #adM, #adS, and then more as I add in more divs).

Comment: Can you show what you mean by updating the code snippit above?

Comment: Would an image help?

Comment: You said you wanted to add `the same text and files (from those same text and file inputs) to multiple divs` - if you want each input to be linked to *its own separate elements*, that's entirely different - everything would be using different text and files, not the *same* text and files. Are you sure that's what you want, *different* text and files linked between elements

Comment: No, its the first thing you said: the same text and files (from those same text and file inputs) to multiple divs. So if you type the word test into the #header input 'test' would show up in every div, and the same thing with the two file inputs.

Comment: See edit - just make an array for each collection of elements you're trying to assign to / listen to, and iterate over them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168964/discussion-between-johnny555-and-certainperformance).

Comment: Would this snippit of JS replace the entire original snippit of JS?